# android andengine examples

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm playing with the checkout of...

[1] http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/checkout

I've checked out the project etc but it appears to almost be looking for a lib as a lot of the imports appear to be broken.

Has anyone ever imported or written a blog post about it? I got different results to the link on [2] http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/getting-started-with-andengine-t11.html and I've read online it's not a good idea at all to use the lib as it's out of date.

How can I import the classes that are missing?

Or better yet it anyone has any other advice on setting up the andengineexamples I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what i use to get me started.

[AndEngine Examples](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/)

Also if you have a android phone search  AndEngine examples on the marktet to see it in action.

Other good tutorials:

Here is a list of tutorials

http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/mimminito-s-tutorial-list-t417.html

Comment: Ah, that's the link I used on [1] :)  Yeah I checked that code out but for some reason it seems to be almost expecting a lib as all the package references seem to be non-existant, so just wondered what everyone else did :)

Comment: Have you downloaded the AndEngine.jar?

Comment: That's no longer in production, it was removed from the build and shouldn't be used any more apparently, according to documentation.